# Android Intent-Extras are not accessed

Tags: android-intent, bundle, extras

So I've been trying to pass an Extra (a single String) from one Activity to another via an Intent. In the following Activity, it is supposed to get the String from the last intent and use it as a condition for another change in Activity.
I do not know if the Extras are not Put, not Gotten or not sent.

Here is the code which is supposed to send the Extras with the Intent:

```
   public void btnDiffClicked(View view) {
    int difficulty = view.getId();
    if (difficulty == R.id.btnDiffEasy) {
        Intent toeasy = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EmotionCheckActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("diff", "EASY");
        toeasy.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", b);
        startActivity(toeasy);
    } else if (difficulty == R.id.btnDiffMedium) {
        Intent tomedium = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EmotionCheckActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("diff", "MEDIUM");
        tomedium.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", b);
        startActivity(tomedium);
    } else if (difficulty == R.id.btnDiffHard) {
        Intent tohard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HardActivity.class);
        startActivity(tohard);
    }
}
```

And here is the code which is supposed to grab the Extras:
            @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_emotion_check);

```
    final Intent startingIntent = getIntent();

    Button btnHelpEmoCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHelpEmoCheck);
    btnHelpEmoCheck.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    Button btnCont = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCont);
    btnCont.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bundle b = startingIntent.getBundleExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT");
                String diff = b.getString("diff");
                    if (diff == "MEDIUM") {
                        Intent tomedium = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MediumActivity.class);
                        startActivity(tomedium);
                    } else if (diff == "EASY") {
                        Intent toeasy = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EasyActivity.class);
                        startActivity(toeasy);
            }
        }
    });
```

When I click the button which calls "btnContClicked" the activity crashes. I also tried getting the extras in onCreate(), when the variables are outside the onCreate()-method. It does not crash then but then the button does not do anything.

```
12-17 13:04:19.078 5900-5900/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
12-17 13:04:19.078 5900-5900/? I/art: VMHOOK: rlim_cur : 0 pid:5900
12-17 13:04:19.458 5900-5900/asap.easel D/Atlas: Validating map...
12-17 13:04:19.508 5900-5957/asap.easel I/Adreno-EGL:              <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1_RB1.05.00.00.002.030_msm8974_refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1_RB1.05.00.00.002.030__release_AU ()
                                                  OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.00
                                                  Build Date: 12/11/14 Thu
                                                  Local Branch: 
                                                  Remote Branch: refs/tags/AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1_RB1.05.00.00.002.030
                                                  Local Patches: NONE
                                                  Reconstruct Branch: NOTHING
12-17 13:04:19.668 5900-5900/asap.easel I/InputMethodManager:    [startInputInner] EditorInfo { packageName=asap.easel, inputType=0x61,    imeOptions=0x4006, privateImeOptions=null },    windowGainingFocus=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@2916a2c,    mServedView=android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{304bccf5 VFED..CL   .F....I. 552,99-1182,222 #7f0b00a7 app:id/textFieldStart}, mServedInputConnectionWrapper=android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ControlledInputConnectionWrapper@23371a8a
12-17 13:04:22.198 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.OutputStream java.net.Socket.getOutputStream()' on a null object reference
12-17 13:04:22.198 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at asap.easel.ConnectionManager.send(ConnectionManager.java:45)
12-17 13:04:22.198 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at asap.easel.LogTherActivity.btnTherClicked(LogTherActivity.java:37)
12-17 13:04:22.198 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-17 13:04:22.198 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-17 13:04:22.198 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:270)
12-17 13:04:22.198 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
12-17 13:04:22.198 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19858)
12-17 13:04:22.198 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-17 13:04:22.198 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-17 13:04:22.198 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
12-17 13:04:22.198 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
12-17 13:04:22.198 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-17 13:04:22.198 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-17 13:04:22.198 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
12-17 13:04:22.198 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
12-17 13:04:22.198 5900-6274/asap.easel D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 13(0x3139322e313638),sn(),hints(known),family  0,flags 4
12-17 13:04:22.198 5900-6274/asap.easel D/libc: [NET]  android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
12-17 13:04:22.228 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.OutputStream java.net.Socket.getOutputStream()' on a null object  reference
12-17 13:04:22.228 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at asap.easel.ConnectionManager.send(ConnectionManager.java:45)
12-17 13:04:22.228 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at asap.easel.ComfyActivity.onCreate(ComfyActivity.java:20)
12-17 13:04:22.228 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5958)
12-17 13:04:22.228 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
12-17 13:04:22.228 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2364)
12-17 13:04:22.228 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2474)
12-17 13:04:22.228 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
12-17 13:04:22.228 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1359)
12-17 13:04:22.228 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-17 13:04:22.228 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
12-17 13:04:22.228 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
12-17 13:04:22.228 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-17 13:04:22.228 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-17 13:04:22.228 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
12-17 13:04:22.228 5900-5900/asap.easel W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
12-17 13:04:22.228 5900-6275/asap.easel D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet+,hn 13(0x3139322e313638),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 4
12-17 13:04:22.228 5900-6275/asap.easel D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornet-, SUCCESS
12-17 13:04:24.388 5900-5915/asap.easel I/art: WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 16.356ms for cause HeapTrim
12-17 13:04:25.188 5900-5900/asap.easel W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

I suppose it is the very last line, yet I do not know what to do with it. All the other lines are referring to my TCP/IP connection. It throws errors when the server is not running, which is not the problem.

Comment: kindly post your error log.

Comment: Oh yes, of course, I will add it.

Comment: does getintent() works in oncreate . ?  means are you able to retrieve the data in oncreate. ?

Comment: try to retrieve the bundle values in a global variable and use it inside click listener.

Comment: Hey Ragu, thanks for your help. My original error is gone, now there is an error when retrieving the Bundle. So, apparently, there is a null pointer exception, thus, there is no bundle sent together with the Intent. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: check your key value and try to find out where the error appears